# Is there software I can use to view my Markdown files as a wiki, with relative links, on Windows

Tags: windows, markdown, wiki

Our team has installed the Markdown Mode extension in Visual Studio on our Windows PCs, and we're happy with that as an editor for Markdown files, but we need a way to generate a wiki from those files where we can click on links that cross-link the files of the wiki. I've been trying to find something, but haven't had any success getting something running.

I tried creating an empty web application and pasting in the html file from here http://dynalon.github.io/mdwiki/#!index.md and naming it index.html, and adding a couple of md files to the same directory that I set to always copy to the build directory, but I got 404-3 errors when it tried to access the .md file.

I see a couple of tools that look possibly good but need Python or Ruby installed, which isn't ideal: http://markdoc.org/quickstart or http://helloform.com/projects/commonplace/

I see this ASP.NET control for embedding a Markdown file into a page http://wikicontrol.codeplex.com/ but the control is for VS 2010 so clearly is not being actively maintained, plus to use it I'll need to build something to take the relative links and find the related .md files and load them up in MVC - sounds like a hassle to get working, and it will require me to put MVC in my docs project.

Is there something that is just designed so that I can put an html file or similar in a directory with a root .md file and have it just immediately act like a wiki and allow navigation between them?

Comment: https://github.com/jgm/gitit might interest you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have decided to use MarkdownDeep NuGet package and a single MVC controller to handle this.  The MVC controller looks at the requested path, uses it to figure out the location of the Markdown file, reads that file and renders it to HTML and returns the HTML.